# How to extract weight value from a Bluetooth LE (SIG) hex value

Tags: xamarin.android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing a xamarin android app to connect to a bluetooth low energy weight scale. I can already connect to the device an explore it's services and characteristics, however i'm facing some problems extracting it's value.

The scale implements the Bluetooth SIG standards, so i was expecting it to have an Weight Scale service (org.bluetooth.service.weight_scale) and the Weight Measurement characteristic (org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_measurement).
Aparently not.

Exploring the device services, the reading service seams to be an "unknown service" (0000ffe0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) and the characteristic seams to be "TI SensorTag Keys Data" (0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb).

Here's some sample readings from the refered service:

- For 78.4  Kg i got E7-58-01-06-20
- For 81.6  Kg i got E7-58-01-06-60
- For 81.7  Kg i got E7-58-01-06-62
- For 118.6 Kg i got E7-58-01-09-44

The scale supports weight reading, body fat, body water, muscle mass, bone mass, basel metabolic rate, and active metabolic rate. I think i'm using a weight read only mode.
I've already converted the hexadecimal values to decimal but the output values are not direct.

What formula should i use to extract the value?

Comment: Could you please share your bluetooth scale manufacturer and model, it could help others facing the same problem?

Comment: Hi Louis Caron, of course i can. I should have done the first way. It's a [SilverCrest Diagnostic Scale SBF 75](https://www.lidl-service.com/static/1231611718/290987_BG.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care only about the last two bytes of your characteristic value: 06-20, 06-60, 0--62 and 09-44.  You can compare those to the weight displayed on the scale:

```
 > 0x620/78.4 -> 20.0
 > 0x660/81.6 -> 20.0
 > 0x662/81.7 -> 20.0
 > 0x944/118.6 -> 20.0
```

This means that each digit in the number represented by the lower two bytes of the characteristic value is equal to 1/20th of one kilogram = 50g.

To display the weight in your application, just convert the last two bytes of the characteristic value into your host integer representation (`ntohs` or equivalent https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs) and divide it by 20.

Comment: Your solution work's fine. I've also tested with pounds. Thank you.